# Default value is not set in datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am trying to set a default value in my bootstrap datetimepicker, but it doe not set up with the default value.

```
var fromDate = "2022-08-24T11:24:00";
$('#inputFromDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY  HH:mm',
    useCurrent: false,
    defaultDate: new Date(new Date(fromDate).setHours(23, 59))
});
```

And my input field looks like this

```
<div class="input-group" id="inputFromDate">
     <input type='text' id="FromDate" name="FromDate" class="form-control valid" placeholder="From Date" />
     <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
     </span>
</div>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defaultDate: "24/08/2022 11:24";
```

or

```
defaultDate: (new Date()).toLocaleString();
```